# Constructor cannot be redeclared. Why?

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, compiler-errors

I have this problem in my Qt C++ program and it says "Constructor cannot be redeclared." How can I fix it?

```
class MagicTransaction : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit MagicTransaction ( QObject* parent = 0 );
private slots:
  void start ( );
  MagicTransaction( QObject* parent );
};
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to happen exactly? Why declare two constructors that accept the exact same argument?

Answer (score 2):

You have two declarations of the `MagicTransaction` constructor that takes a `QObject*` argument - one in the `public` section and one in the `private` section (note that the default value and the `explicit` modifier don't take part in the name mangling). Just remove one and you should be fine:

```
class MagicTransaction : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit MagicTransaction ( QObject* parent = 0 );
private slots:
  void start ( );
  // second definition removed here
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply - you have declared the same constructor twice and in different sections:

```
class MagicTransaction : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit MagicTransaction ( QObject* parent = 0 );
private slots:
  void start ( );
  MagicTransaction( QObject* parent ); // <---- remove this
};
```

Remove the second declaration

Answer (score 1):

You have the constructor

```
explicit MagicTransaction ( QObject* parent = 0 );
```

and then you have a function that is

```
MagicTransaction( QObject* parent );
```

Slots are functions hence you have two identical functions one of which is a constructor and the other - not. Rename the second and you will be good to go.

Comment: They are both declarations for the same constructor, as the error message is saying.

Comment: Or is this something Qt-specific? (sorry I didn't notice, removed my downvote)

Comment: @walnut no, you are right, slots are basically just declared like normal functions within the "slot" section - but you can't put a constructor there AFAIK and it certainly can't be a duplicate of a constructor (as normal)

Comment: @rbaleksandar your answer looks fine to me, I think walnut removed his -1, so not sure where the other one came from, anyway, +1 to fix injustice

Comment: @code_fodder XD I'm not about the - or +. It's just I was confused about that comment in particular.

Comment: @rbaleksandar I read your answer and initially downvoted because you seem to imply that the second declaration is not a constructor declaration (which it is by standard C++ grammar). Then I realized the `slots` keyword in the question and since I don't really know much about Qt, removed my downvote (someone else had already downvoted) and posted the second comment, leaving the first so that someone could clarify for me (as @code_fodder did).

Comment: Ah, ok. I guess if you are not familiar with `slots` (or `signals` for that matter) it can be confusing. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

I have *never* seen a constructor used as a slot in Qt, that seems bizarre.

Slots are called only *after* an object is fully constructed, and I'm pretty certain C++ disallows constructing the same object more than once.

If you want a slot that will somehow accept a parent pointer (I'm not sure if you're trying to change ownership of the object in the Qt hierarchy, that also seems unusual but I *think* it's possible), you'll need to call it something else, like:

```
void ChangeMyOwner(QObject *parent);
```